# git how to switch back locally to remote master

Tags: git, branch

I have a local git project synced with a remote github project. I created a remote branch using browser/GUI, XYZ, and switched my local git workspace to that branch for local development, using following commands on my laptop:

```
git fetch

git checkout --track origin/XYZ

#\<do some local coding and commit\>

git push

#\<do some remote editing on a branch file using browser and commit\>

git pull
```

So far, push/pull was seamless. Now I am done with stabilising the branch code, and want to switch back **local** workspace to local master branch, and **simultaneously** make it start tracking remote master branch, so that git push/pull, without any -b/-B kind of switches, work simply with the remote master branch. However, following command does not work:

`git checkout --track origin/master`

Any idea how to make local workspace switch back to master branch and start tracking remote master as well?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what are you trying on the command window. But I gonna try to give you some tips might be useful that I know.

First of all could you look up your branches with:

```
$git branch
```

And it will prompt all the branches you have. Then try it to switch if they exist:

```
$git switch master
```

or

```
$git checkout -b master
```

Could you more specific, I will try to help you.

Comment: Thanks Joe. The first part helps. git checkout -b master helps switching the branch to master locally. Simultaneously, I want it to track the remote "master" branch as well, so that during git push(/pull), I do not need to give the full "git push -u origin master", rather, just work with "git push". How to do so?

Comment: Hmmm. According to your comment I can just say: when you clone (or pull) a repo from the origin you got all the files and logs. What you do on your local going to be save to the log file. You might be consider it as an update. So you've added new commits, when you look from vim with **$git log** you can see what you've commit. Or you can track the changes wtih **$git status**

Comment: Thanks. I tried "git checkout master" (without -b option since master exists), followed by a first push using "git push -u origin master". That added an upstream tracking reference for the current branch, as HEAD. Next push/pull happened without any command line options.